# Magento custom module licensing - Magento Connect

Tags: magento, licensing, magento-1.7

I have created a custom payment gateway module which allows to integrate a particular bank's payment gateway into a person's Magento site. Now what I want to do is to upload this module as a commercial module so that other people can pay,download and can use it in their sites.

My problem is which licensing method should I use from below? Are there any coding standards to be followed to it be a commercial module? Are there any other procedures to be taken? How should I proceed?

[image]

Comment: Probably belongs over here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it about licensing

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dasun, use `Custom License`. And then in `License URL` you have to give link explaining custom terms and conditions for this license. If you are creating custom terms, then better have a link on your site, something like EULA (End-user License Agreement)?

For example what it should have in it, check this http://magentools.com/eula/

For commercial extensions you will need to provide a link where users will be able to navigate to purchase your extension.

You give YOUR website link where you will sell your extension. Magento DOES NOT sell your extension, it just displays your extension and gives buyer a link to your website. You will handle the payment OUTSIDE of Magento (your website), payment method can be anything, you will configure it and Magento does not care about it as it's outside their scope.

Best way is to configure your payment in a way that once the said payment is made, the extension will automatically emailed to the buyer. If you are manually verifying the payment, mention in the extension description or your terms that it will take X hours/days to email extension after payment is successfully made.

Comment: +1 for the info. Let me look into that

Comment: It says "Magento Commercial Extensions: Magento Commercial extensions are contributions offered for sale by Magento community members or partners. However, the sale transaction, distribution and licensing is managed by the seller and occur outside Magento." If I manage to handle payment outside How can I allow client to download the module outside the Magento store? How he gets the module?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the support